# Get imei from QByteArray in hex

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a desktop application which receives frames in bytes format from a server. I have the imei of the device sending those frames inside the frames received.

I have tried to add to a `long long` variable with the corresponding left shift to each byte (`56, 48, 40..., 0`) but number is longer than `40 bits` so it does not work.

I just want it to put on a text box so in `QString` format would be enough but I am not confident at all with C++ and I don't see how I can get it.

For example, this imei: `352353222952355` would be received in a frame like this: `[0x00, 0x01, 0x40, 0x76, 0xA0, 0xB0, 0x85, 0xA3]` which I have in my `QByteArray`. Each time I try to print that variable with qDebug(), I get the hex representation ("\x00\0x...."). What I want to get is the number as I put on the first line in this paragraph.

How can I convert to its decimal representation in a `QString`?

EDIT: 
I want to add some information related to the test I am running with the help of @Peter

This is what I get if I print the QByteArray:

```
qDebug() << imei;
"\x00\x01@v\x98[\xD7\xAF"
```

In case I pass that imei (QByteArray) to your function, I get:
QString imeiStr;
imeiStr = ConvertToQString(imei);

```
qDebug() << imeiStr;
"\u0000\u0001@v?[\u05EF"
```

If I debug the application and show both variables (imei and imeiStr) I see some differences:

[image]

imeiStr is shorter and also, from position 4, differs from the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
quint8 source[8] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x40, 0x76, 0xA0, 0xB0, 0x85, 0xA3};
QByteArray imei;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
    imei.append(source[i]);
}

qlonglong val = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
    val *= 256;
    val += (quint8)imei.at(i);
}
qDebug() << QString::number(val);
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much! I was trying to shift the number instead of multiplying.

Comment: Shifting for long long is not available, I got the same problem with you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stringstreams:

```
#include <sstream>

QString ConvertToQString(const QByteArray& array)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
        ss << array[i];

    return QString::fromStdString(ss.str());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error at the return. "no matching conversion for functional-style cast form..." I guess QString does not have that converter. I will check

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've modified the code. Please check this out.

Comment: I just added some information about your function. Please, check it.